# Add extra ports to existing ssl certificates

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, xmpp, peerjs

I have my domain which has SSL enabled, now I have configured some port on that same domain.

I want to know how can I add more port into that existing SSL cert file.

I have hosted site on Dreamhost, but as I configured custom port they refuse to help.

Comment: Do i need to add in apache conf file ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how can I add more port into that existing SSL cert file.

The certificate contains only the host name. It is independent of the port, so you could use it for any port on this host. Of course you still need to configure your web server to actually listen on this port with SSL, but this would be different question.

Comment: Thanks for response,  can you please guide me how can i do this?

Comment: Again: "this would be different question". And questions about server setup belong to serverfault.com. Apart from that there is no general answer, because it is specific to the server used and which ways you have to administrate the server, so please add all these details when asking.